# Definition of Linear independence of algebraic $1$-forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

"Suppose that $a,b,c,d$ are linearly independent algebraic $1$-forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$".

What does it mean for algebraic $1$-forms to be linearly independent? I have looked through my notes and cannot find a definition.

An algebraic k-form on a vector space V is function on $V^k$ such that it is linear in each argument and changes sign under the interchange of two arguments. (I think these are tensors of type $(k,0)$).

Comment: what is an algebraic 1-form?

Comment: @janmarqz I have added the definition of algebraic $k$-form.

Comment: Note that for 1-forms there are no "two-arguments".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Take a linear combination $L=k_1a+k_2b+k_3c+k_4d$ and evaluate at a vector $X$ for which $a(X)=1$ , $b(X)=0$ , $c(X)=0$  and $d(X)=0$.

Comment: use the definition that $L=0$ means $L(Y)=0$ , $\forall Y\in{\mathbb{R}}^n$